model.fit() get error : UNIMPLEMENTED: Cast string to float is not supported
I don't understand where my mistake came from. I've looked at various sources, but the error is always the same...
I have the following error:
UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported
I found this similary question: Link - stackoverflow
I can't see how to adapt it on my code...
My code is based on the following tutorial: Link - original tutorial
For example, my CSV file contains :
 0 id : “azxje23d"
 1 type : 2
 2 raw : “PAYPAL - Netflix Subscription”
 3 type_paiement : “PRELEVEMENT
 4 label : “Netflix Abonnement”
 5 amount : 22,4
 6 Category : “Subscriptions"

Code snippet:
df = pd.read_csv('based-systems-recommandation/MappingTransactions.csv', on_bad_lines='skip', sep=';', skiprows=1, names=['id', 'date', 'rdate', 'vdate', 'type', 'raw', 'type_paiement', 'label', 'amount', 'Income', 'Expense', 'balance', 'Readable label', 'Account','Company', 'Category', 'Share','Primary', 'planned', 'State'])
    df = df.drop(["date", "rdate", "vdate", "Expense","Income","balance","Readable label","Readable label","Account","Company","Share","Primary","planned","State"], axis = 1)
    
    df["amount"] = [float(str(i).replace(",", ".")) for i in df["amount"]]
    
    
    # Check the data type of the columns and if data is missing
    df.info()
    
    
    # Split data into training and validation dataframes using sample() method from Pandas
    
    train_dataframe=df.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=200)
    val_dataframe=df.drop(train_dataframe.index) 
    
    print(
        "Using %d samples for training and %d for validation"
        % (len(train_dataframe), len(val_dataframe))
    )
    
    # Convert data from Pandas dataframe to Tensorflow dataset format
    
    def dataframe_to_dataset(df):
        df = df.copy()
        labels=df.pop("Category")
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df), labels))
        print(ds)
        return ds
    
    train_ds = dataframe_to_dataset(train_dataframe)
    val_ds = dataframe_to_dataset(val_dataframe)
    
    #print(train_ds)
    #print(val_ds)
    
    # Create the batches of the Tensorflow Data
    
    train_ds = train_ds.batch(5) ## For training
    val_ds = val_ds.batch(5) ## For validation
    
    # Have a look at the first batch
    
    dataset_filter = train_ds.take(1)
    result = list(dataset_filter.as_numpy_iterator())

    # We have to create different layers to process the raw input. 
    # The first layer required is the input layer.
    
    id = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="id", dtype="string")
    raw = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="raw", dtype="string")
    type_paiement = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="type_paiement", dtype="string")
    label = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="label", dtype="string")
    
    type = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="type", dtype='int64')
    amount = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="amount", dtype='float32')
    
    # Joining input blocks in an array
    
    all_inputs=[
        id, 
        raw, 
        type_paiement, 
        label, 
        type, 
        amount
    ]
    
    # Next Layer, we define an encoder layer : converts categorical dara into one-hot encoding & normalizes numerical data
    # We need to let it learn the vocabulary(range of input data) as a preprocessing step
    
    # Create a lookup layer which will turn strings into integer indices
    def encode_categorical_feature(feature, name, dataset):
        ... Original code
        return encoder
    
    # Create a lookup layer for numerical inputs encoder layer
    def encode_numerical_feature(feature, name, dataset):
        ... Original code
        return encoder
    
    id_encoded = encode_categorical_feature(id,"id", train_ds)
    raw_encoded = encode_categorical_feature(raw, "raw", train_ds)
    type_paiement_encoded = encode_categorical_feature(type_paiement, "type_paiement", train_ds)
    label_encoded = encode_categorical_feature(label, "label", train_ds)
    
    type_encoded = encode_numerical_feature(type, "type", train_ds)
    amount_encoded = encode_numerical_feature(amount, "amount", train_ds)
    
    # Concatenate the Encoders to form the next layer (Encoder layer)
    
    all_features = layers.concatenate(
        [
            id_encoded,
            raw_encoded,
            type_paiement_encoded,
            label_encoded,
            type_encoded,
            amount_encoded
        ]
    )
    
    x= layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(all_features)
    x= layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    output= layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    model= tf.keras.Model(inputs=all_inputs, outputs=output)
    model.compile("adam", "binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.summary()
    
    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model,show_shapes=True,rankdir='LR', to_file='model.png')
    
    target_data = train_dataframe["Category"] 
    model.fit(train_ds, epochs=100, validation_data=val_ds)

Error :
Epoch 1/100
2024-05-29 22:36:03.489463: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:117] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2024-05-29 22:36:03.721447: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1816] OP_REQUIRES failed at cast_op.cc:122 : UNIMPLEMENTED: Cast string to float is not supported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Finance LLMs Analyzer/based-systems-recommandation/mainv2.py", line 175, in <module>
    model.fit(train_ds, epochs=100, validation_data=val_ds)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node compile_loss/binary_crossentropy/Cast defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNIMPLEMENTED:  Cast string to float is not supported
         [[{{node compile_loss/binary_crossentropy/Cast}}]]
  (1) CANCELLED:  Function was cancelled before it was started
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_6128]

Logs :
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   id             312 non-null    object 
 1   type           312 non-null    int64  
 2   raw            312 non-null    object 
 3   type_paiement  312 non-null    object 
 4   label          312 non-null    object 
 5   amount         312 non-null    float64
 6   Category       312 non-null    object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(5)
memory usage: 17.2+ KB
Using 250 samples for training and 62 for validation
Model: "functional_1"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                  ┃ Output Shape              ┃         Param # ┃ Connected to               ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ id (InputLayer)               │ (None, 1)                 │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ raw (InputLayer)              │ (None, 1)                 │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ type_paiement (InputLayer)    │ (None, 1)                 │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ label (InputLayer)            │ (None, 1)                 │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ type (InputLayer)             │ (None, 1)                 │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ amount (InputLayer)           │ (None, 1)                 │               0 │ -                          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ string_lookup (StringLookup)  │ (None, 251)               │               0 │ id[0][0]                   │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ string_lookup_1               │ (None, 156)               │               0 │ raw[0][0]                  │
│ (StringLookup)                │                           │                 │                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ string_lookup_2               │ (None, 6)                 │               0 │ type_paiement[0][0]        │
│ (StringLookup)                │                           │                 │                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ string_lookup_3               │ (None, 114)               │               0 │ label[0][0]                │
│ (StringLookup)                │                           │                 │                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ normalization (Normalization) │ (None, 1)                 │               3 │ type[0][0]                 │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ normalization_1               │ (None, 1)                 │               3 │ amount[0][0]               │
│ (Normalization)               │                           │                 │                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ concatenate (Concatenate)     │ (None, 529)               │               0 │ string_lookup[0][0],       │
│                               │                           │                 │ string_lookup_1[0][0],     │
│                               │                           │                 │ string_lookup_2[0][0],     │
│                               │                           │                 │ string_lookup_3[0][0],     │
│                               │                           │                 │ normalization[0][0],       │
│                               │                           │                 │ normalization_1[0][0]      │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ dense (Dense)                 │ (None, 64)                │          33,920 │ concatenate[0][0]          │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ dropout (Dropout)             │ (None, 64)                │               0 │ dense[0][0]                │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ dense_1 (Dense)               │ (None, 1)                 │              65 │ dropout[0][0]              │
└───────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
 Total params: 33,991 (132.79 KB)
 Trainable params: 33,985 (132.75 KB)
 Non-trainable params: 6 (32.00 B)


The binary cross entropy loss function you're using expects the labels to be a float (between 0 and 1), however the labels you're providing are strings. You need to convert your strings to a floating point value. One option is to map each of your categories to a specific number in your data pipeline. For example, you could assign 0.0 to "Subscriptions", and 1.0 to your other category.
Do note that the loss function you're using is made for binary classification. If you have more than two categories, you will need to do some modifications. I would suggest reading this tutorial, especially the part on multi-class classification: Basic Text Classification

Thanks, I found the function 'pd.get_dummies()' can it work ? like ' = pd.get_dummies(train_dataframe, columns=train_dataframe, drop_first=True)' ?

That's another question. I'm not familiar with pandas so I can't really answer.
